Should Faddeev-Popov ghosts (in path integral) belong to infinite-dimensional Grassmann (Banach) algebra?
Many years ago, I had the opportunity to study gauge theories based on the book by Faddeev and Slavnov. The Faddeev-Popov ghost fields in the path integral for the Yang-Mills (YM)  theory did not cause me any questions at that time (I knew the Berezin integral). Moreover, I have (as an exercise) independently calculated one-loop renormalization group quantities in the theory of YM and QCD - beta function and anomalous dimensions of fields for arbitrary semisimple Lie group. Now, recalling past calculations in connection with the preparation of a review for some dissertation, I asked myself the question: to which set do the ghost fields (in the path integral) belong? In the past, I believed that they simply belong to the odd part of some Grassmann algebra - the dimension did not interest me then. But now, I have a conviction that they must belong to the odd part of an infinite-dimensional complete normalized Grassmann algebra (i.e. Grassmann-Banach algebra). The arguments in favor of this statement are very simple and lie on the surface. In the case of a finite-dimensional Grassmann algebra, the ghost fields $c^a$, $a=1,...,n$ ($n$ is the dimension of the Lie group) are "cut off" according to the group index $a$, which is also the case for anti-ghost fields $b_a =\bar{c}_a$. Highly likely  that in this case the renormalization and "unitarity" of the theory will also be violated. As for the norm for the infinite-dimensional Grassmann algebra, it is necessary for the correct definition of derivatives with respect to (odd) ghost variables, for example, of the type $b_a=\partial/\partial c^a$, which arise in a number of formalisms using an extended phase space (with odd-variables). I note that here we come close to superanalysis in the interpretation of A. Rogers and her followers. (The same approach gives her own interpretation of the Berezin integral.)

FWIW, a field (of any Grassmann-parity) in $d>0$ spacetime dimensions generates an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

I have found a support to use of infinite-dimensional Grassmann algebras in the book of Henneaux and Teitelboim  (1991). (See page 139 of this book.)
